# How can I add a manual APOC index to a property that contains a list of strings

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to add a fulltext index on a field which contains a list of strings.  For example, a `Strings` node might look like this:

```
{
    "strings": ["hello", "world"]
}
```

I'm adding an index using the following command:

```
CALL apoc.index.addAllNodes("mystrings", {Strings: ["strings"]});
```

However, when I attempt to search against that index using the following, I always come back with an empty set.

```
CALL apoc.index.search("mystrings", "hello")
```